# all schemes MUST be satisfied for a request to be authorized using annotation

Tags: annotations, swagger, openapi

OpenAPI Specification [states](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0.html#security-requirement-object):

> When a list of Security Requirement Objects is defined on the OpenAPI Object or Operation Object, only one of the Security Requirement Objects in the list needs to be satisfied to authorize the request.

The example provided is:

```yaml
security:    # A AND B

- A
  B
```

How to do this using Swagger Java annotations?

I tried

```java
@SecurityRequirement(name = "A")
@SecurityRequirement(name = "B")
```

also

```java
@SecurityRequirements(value = [SecurityRequirement(name = "A"),
SecurityRequirement(name = "B")] )
```

but both of them produce:

```yaml
security:    # A OR B

- A
- B
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there's no way to express that using Swagger Java annotations. Here are the related issues / enhancement requests on GitHub:

- [[ENHANCEMENT] Require multiple security schemes (all, not some)](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/2744)
- [Multiple SecurityRequirements annotations with AND condition](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/3556)

As a workaround, you can post-process your generated OpenAPI file (e.g. using tools like `yq` or `jq`) and add/fix the `security` section as needed.

Comment: Yeah, I just want to make sure there is no solution. Thank u for the reply. But If I post process OpenAPI file, I need to do this everytime I rebuild the project, this is kinda painful.

Answer (score 0):

This is supported by the MicroProfile APIs, like this. You define the security schemes and the requirement set:

```
@SecurityScheme(
    securitySchemeName = "accessKey",
    type = SecuritySchemeType.APIKEY,
    apiKeyName = "X-Access-Key",
    in = SecuritySchemeIn.HEADER
)
@SecurityScheme(
    securitySchemeName = "secretKey",
    type = SecuritySchemeType.APIKEY,
    apiKeyName = "X-Secret-Key",
    in = SecuritySchemeIn.HEADER
)
@SecurityRequirementsSet(
    value = {@SecurityRequirement(name="accessKey"), @SecurityRequirement(name="secretKey")}
 )
```

And it generates correct openapi:

```
      security:
      - accessKey: []
        secretKey: []
```